# getting 404 after submitting login form in codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, routes

I am facing problem with login form it gives 404 when I submit the form. Is it a routing issue or some thing else because my .htacess file is already in root and fine ?
Here is my controller:

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Login extends MX_Controller
    {  
    function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
    }  

 function index(){
         $this->load->view('login_form');

    }
    public function submit_login()
        {
            $username = $this->input->post('txtUserName');
            $password = $this->input->post('txtPassword');
            //echo "...../////".$username . " dsds" .$password;exit;

                $row = Modules::run('admin_users/_get_where_login',$username, $password )->row_array();

                    if (empty($row)) {
                        //echo "Invalid user name........."; exit();
                        redirect(ADMIN_BASE_URL);
                        exit();
                    }

                    if(!empty($row) && isset($row)) {

                        $data['all_data'] = $row;
                        $this->session->set_userdata('user_data', $data);
                        $user_data = $this->session->userdata('user_data'); 

                    }
                    redirect(ADMIN_BASE_URL.'dashboard');
        }


    function logout(){
        session_destroy();
        session_write_close();
        $this->session->unset_userdata('user_data');
        $this->index(); 
        }

    }
```

Here is my view file

```
 <div class="panel-body">
               <p class="text-center pv">SIGN IN TO CONTINUE.</p>
               <?php

          $attributes = array('autocomplete' => 'off', 'id' => 'login');
          echo form_open(ADMIN_BASE_URL.'login/submit_login',$attributes);
          echo '<div class="form-group has-feedback">';
          $data = array(
              'name'        => 'txtUserName',
              'id'          => 'txtUserName',
              'class'       => 'form-control',
              'value'       => '',
            );
      echo form_input($data);
      echo '<span class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback text-muted"></span>';
      echo '</div>';       

      echo '<div class="form-group has-feedback">';
          $data = array(
              'name'        => 'txtPassword',
              'id'          => 'txtPassword',
              'class'       => 'form-control',
              'type'        =>'password',
              'value'       => '',
            );
      echo form_input($data);
      echo '<span class="fa fa-lock form-control-feedback text-muted"></span>';
      echo '</div>';         

         ?>            

                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary mt-lg">Login</button>
               </form>

            </div>
         </div>
```

here is .htacess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|static|uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] 

#Redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Check URL is working. Put `echo ADMIN_BASE_URL.'login/submit_login';exit;` before `div.panel-body`.

Comment: ok its working and giving me

Comment: http://localhost/test/admin/login/submit_login

Comment: For testing sake, try with `index.php` i.e. ADMIN_BASE_URL.'index.php/login/submit_login' in form tag.

Comment: i have already tested it but no luck

Comment: Something else is wrong than. Make one testing method with code from [basic example](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#the-form).

Comment: seems like that should route to localhostt/login/submit_login

you should post your htaccess